# Is there a better way to Calculate remaining time until open - Timer?

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a countdown timer and I have got an issue when the `close` is reached I am trying to display the `timeremaing` until the `open`of the next day. Right now I have done the `code`but it is calculating on `open`of the same day and not on the next day.

Below is a part of the entire `code`.

```js
var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var nextday = (nextday) = current.getDay(+1);
var currentTime = (currentTime) = (current.getHours() * 60) + current.getMinutes();
var remainTime = 0;
var closeTime = (openTime[day].close *60);
var openNextday = (openNextday) = nextday - (openTime[nextday].open *60);
var openTime = (openTime[day].open *60);

else if (closeTime - currentTime <= 0) {
     remainTime = currentTime - openNextday;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "open in " + Math.floor(remainTime/60)+ " hours " + Math.floor(remainTime%60) + " Mins";

}
```

Comment: else without if?

Comment: No, it is not working since there is more `statements`. Even if I remove `if` the calculation will still be on the same day and are not calculating the time until `open`the next day.@SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: Why don;t you use moment.js for playing with the time